# VS Code: Remote Debugging with Local Files (Go)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a remote machine that has physical hardware attached that my Go code interfaces with. The code must be run on this remote machine for it to work.

I'm using VS Code on a separate machine. I'd like to keep the code files *local* (on the development machine), as it has all of the version control and such set up properly, but run the Go debugger on the *remote* machine. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I know VS Code supports remote development over SSH, but it requires the source code files to also be on the remote machine.

Comment: write a virtual file system so the remote system can access your local files, open a virtual workspace on this virtual file system

Comment: If you just need to run the compiled binary on the remote machine, consider the [remote debugging feature](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#remote-debugging) - at minimum, `dlv` should be available and can run from the remote machine. Where to compile the binary and how to ship the compiled binary to the remote machine may need custom setup work (you can wire it with to the debug launch config as a prelaunch task in theory.)